# Исключение JAVA throws

Tags: java, try-catch

метод printOddNumbers, принимает массив и выводит в консоль только нечетные числа из него, через запятую. Как здесь добавить исключение если в метод будет передан массив нулевой длинны.

```
public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(arr[i]).append(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.substring(0,stringBuilder.length()-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете проверку длины массива и бросаете исключение, если длина нулевая.

```
if (arr.length == 0) {
    throw new MyException();
}
```